# how to create a plot with customized points in R?

Tags: r, graphics, plot

I know I can create a plot with line and dots using the type = "o" argument in the plot command. I would like some more control over this -- I want to be able to draw the "o" as *full* dots, with black border and fill-in color of my choice, of customized size and of a different color than the line. Same for the line, I want to make it thicker, and of my choice of color. How would I go on about doing that?

What I found until now is just a plain

```
 plot(y, type= "o")
```

which is too poor for my needs.

I am not interested in using ggplot, but instead use the internal plot library of R.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Take a careful look at `?points`, including running the examples (`example("points")`) ...

Comment: thanks. I will look at ?points, but the examples do not seem to present what I need. they do have a solid circle, but without a border.

Comment: Look more carefully, at the second plot (light blue background, dark blue edge), third plot (point types 21-25; yellow background, red edge)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use layering (I don't work in base too much any more as a social researcher I love the facet_grid of ggplot, so there may be a better way) as in:

```
x <- sort(rnorm(25))
y <- sort(rnorm(25))
z <- as.factor(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 25, r=TRUE))

plot(x, y, pch = 19, cex = 1.3)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(x, y, pch = 19, cex = 1, col = z)
```

Which gives you:
[image]

Comment: I suggest adding opar <- par(new = TRUE) before the second call to 'plot', and par(opar) after (to prevent surprises in the future).  Or replace the second call to 'plot' with a call to 'points' (with the same arguments).

Comment: Layering is unnecessary to achieve points with coloured fill. `bg` and `pch=21` will do the trick.

Answer (score 15):

All the information you need should be present in `?plot` and `?points`, as suggested by @BenBolker. In particular, you want to be using `pch=21`, and specifying background colour with the `bg` argument, size with `cex`, and line width with `lwd`.

If you want the line to be a different thickness to the point borders, you need to plot the line first, and then overlay the points.

For example:

```
y <- sample(10)
plot(y, lwd=6, type='l')
points(y, bg='tomato2', pch=21, cex=3, lwd=3) # tomato2 is a personal fave
```

[image]

You could also provide a vector of `lwd`, `cex` and `col` to the points call:

```
plot(y, lwd=6, type='l')
points(y, bg=rainbow(10), pch=21, cex=seq(1, by=0.2, length.out=10), 
       lwd=seq(2, by=1, length.out=10))
```

[image]