# Border color of plot points - R plot

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create a plot with customized points in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958025/how-to-create-a-plot-with-customized-points-in-r)

I know in R you can use plot to specify the color of the points

`plot(......,col="red")` makes the points in a scatter plot, for example, red.

How can I specify the border color of the points such that the border color is different from the fill color.

Comment: You can plot twice. Once with a "rim color" and second with the "fill color", but the plotting character should be smaller (`cex`). Hadley does something similar in ggplot2 here: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_point.html (scroll down towards the end).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `bg` parameter to handle how a point is filled. On certain types of plotting characters, this will be visible. For example...

```
plot(1,1,col=3, bg=2, pch=23)
```

Comment: The color is specified in the above command. You can use `col="red", bg="green"` if you'd prefer. I'm using integers.

Comment: For circles, use plot(1,1,col=3, bg=2, pch=21)