# How to Place a border around points for the scatter plot with gradient color and shape in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, visualization, data-visualization

My goal is to place the border around points in `scatter plot` WHICH has the **gradient color** and **gradient shape** based on the value (as you can see in following script).

```
ggplot(filname, aes(Va1, Var2, col= PR, size=PR)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(list(title = "Title", y = "Var2", x = "Var1")) +
  xlim(0, 150) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(7)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 150, 12))

** PR is the third Var in my data.
```

The generated plot
[image]

I found the following questions here:

- [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506630/control-point-border-thickness-in-ggplot)
- [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506630/control-point-border-thickness-in-ggplot)
- [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958025/how-to-create-a-plot-with-customized-points-in-r)

but really they do not work in my case due to the two reasons I bolded above, I want to keep the **gradient color** and **gradient shape** but at the same time add the border around the points to make them more appreciable.

Basically, to make outline colour in ggplot I found we would have :

1. fill
2. colour for border

Considering this when I act accordingly as below

```
ggplot(PR_Grt100_REL_80, aes(Age, SC, col= PR, size=PR)) + 
  geom_point(aes (fill= PR), colour = "black") +
  labs(list(title = "Title", y = "Var2", x = "Var1")) +
  xlim(0, 150) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(7)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 150, 12))
```

I would get the following graph!

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated?

Comment: Difficult to test without the data but you use `scale_color_gradientn` which apply to the colour, and I think it would make sense to use `scale_fill_gradientn` instead. Also drop `col=PR` in the first aes (as you use fill in `geom_point`

Comment: @timat Thanks but it did not change anything. Regarding the data, it is huge and unfortunately impossible to put them here!

Comment: you could add just the first 10 rows of it with `dput(head(df, 10))` or alternatively use a built in set like `mtcars` or `iris`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you need to do is to use a shape that respects `fill` and `color`. Shapes 21:25 have this property, http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/shape.

Using `mtcars`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp, fill = cyl, size = cyl)) +
    geom_point(shape = 21, stroke = 2) + # change the thickness of the boarder with stroke
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rainbow(7)) +
    scale_size(range = c(2,6)) # only for example visibility
```

[image]